# Как запустить установку .apk из кода?

Tags: android, kotlin

для обновления приложения скачиваю apk'шку и пытаюсь запустить её:

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
startActivity(intent)
```

при этом на android 7 выдает :

> exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

на других версиях android всё ok...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282

Comment: Спасибо) очень помогли.

Answer (score 4):

в manifest добавил :

```
<provider
   android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
   android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
   android:exported="false"
   android:grantUriPermissions="true">
   <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
      android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

provider_paths:

```
<paths>
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
```

для корректной работы на android 7:

```
var fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file)
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24)    
   fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file)
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fileUri)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true)
intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
context.startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Код срабатывает.
Но при запуске установке отваливается по ошибке "Ошибка при синтаксическом анализе пакета" Если пакет запустить вручную, то установка проходит только с предупреждением о неизвестном источнике. Смена флага Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE на false не помогает

Comment: проверьте разрешения, была такая проблема, но уже не помню как решил.