# Запуск установки приложение по нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android

Пожалуйста помогите с таким вопросом...
Делаю простое приложение которое скачивает apk файл и запускает его на установку.
Проблем с скачиванием файла нет, а вот открыть не могу...
Путь известен название apk файла тоже но выдает следующие ощибки:

```
exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

вот код на запуск файла:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse (Uri.fromFile(new File (t)).toString ().replace("file://", "content://")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Возможно дубликат вопроса [Как запустить установку .apk из кода?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1053161/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-apk-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0)